# Setting state in react. Is there a better way to write this without warning errors?

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation

I am working on a registration form on react. I am a bit stuck with the validation part of it.

As of now I am getting the following warnings four times on the console:  "warning  Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()  react/no-direct-mutation-state."

I am guessing the reason I am getting these errors is because of statements like these "this.state.errors.firstName = "First name must be at least 2 characters.";" and like this"this.state.errors = {};" in my code.

However, I do not know how to make this better and eliminate the  warnings. If you can provide a better way for me to do this that would be awesome. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import HeaderPage from './HeaderPage';

import Logo from './Logo';

import RegistrationForm from './RegistrationForm';

import axios from 'axios';

class Registration extends Component {   

  mixins: [
    Router.Navigation
  ];

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
        firstName:'',
        lastName:'',
        email:'',
        errors:{},
        helpText: '',
        helpUrl: '',
        nextLink:''
    };

    this.setUserState = this.setUserState.bind(this);
    this.registrationFormIsValid = this.registrationFormIsValid.bind(this);
    this.saveUser = this.saveUser.bind(this);
  }

  setUserState(e){
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({[name]: value});
    //delete this line
    console.log(this.state[name]);

  }

  registrationFormIsValid(){

    var formIsValid = true;
    this.state.errors = {};
    //validate first name
    if(this.state.firstName.length < 2){
      this.state.errors.firstName = "First name must be at least 2 characters.";
      formIsValid = false;
    }
    //validate last name
    if(this.state.lastName.length < 2){
      this.state.errors.lastName = "Last name must be at least 2 characters.";
      formIsValid = false;
    }
    //validate email
    if(this.state.email.length < 2){
      this.state.errors.email = "Email must be at least 2 characters.";
      formIsValid = false;
    }

    this.setState({errors : this.state.errors});

    return formIsValid;


  }

  saveUser(e, { history }){
    e.preventDefault();

    // const errorWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('input'); 

    // for (var i=0; i < errorWrappers.length; i++) {
    // const isError= errorWrappers[i].innerHTML;
    //   if (isError.length > 0){
    //     errorWrappers[i].previousSibling.className = "error-input"
    //   }
    // } 

    if(!this.registrationFormIsValid()){
      return;
    }



    const values = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      phone: this.state.phone,
      address: this.state.address,
      dob: this.state.birthday
    }

    if (this.props.userRole === 'instructor'){

      axios.post(`/instructors`, values)
      .then((response)=> {
        //delete this line
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error + 'something went wrooooong');
      });
      this.props.history.push("/success-instructor");

    }else{
       axios.post(`/students`, values)
      .then((response)=> {
        //delete this line
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error + 'something went wrooooong');
      });

      if (this.props.parent === "false"){
        this.props.history.push("/success-student");
      }else{
        this.props.history.push("/success-parent");
      }
    }

  }
  //end of validation

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Registration">

        <div className="container menu buttons">
          <HeaderPage/>
        </div>

        <div className="page container narrow">

          <div className="cover-content">

            <Logo/> 

            <div className="container">

              <h2 className="page-title">{this.props.title}</h2>

              <a className="helpLink" href={this.props.helpUrl}>{this.props.helpText}</a>

              <div className="main-content background-white">

               <RegistrationForm
                userRole={this.props.userRole}
                onChange={this.setUserState}
                onSave={this.saveUser}
                errors={this.state.errors}
                  />

                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Registration);
```

Comment: anytime you want to change a piece of state you can use `this.setState({ pieceOfState: new_value });`

Comment: @AmrAly Yes you are right. I think the challenge is in that in this case errors is an object with nested key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
this.state.errors = {};
```

and

```
this.state.errors.lastName = "Last name must be at least 2 characters.";
```

use

```
this.setState({errors = {}});
this.setState({ errors: { lastName: "Last name must be at least 2 characters." } });
```

You need to avoid directly mutating the state.

The Warning itself answers the question. Please read the React Doc
carefully.

> "warning Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state."

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried it this way but now I am not getting the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mutate `state`
Don't ever have code that directly changes state. Instead, create new object and change it. After you are done with changes update state with `setState`.

Instead of:

```
 this.state.errors.someError1="e1";
 this.state.errors.someError2="e2";
```

do this:

```
this.errorsObject=Object.assign({},this.state.errors,{someError1:"e1",someError2:"e2"};
```

and in the end:

```
  this.setState({
  errors:this.errorsObject
  });
```

> Object.assign lets us merge one object's properties into another one, replacing values of properties with matching names. We can use this to copy an object's values without altering the existing one.